# eclipselink query-results-cache does not work

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink

I have an entity with named query.

```
@Entity(name = "MyEntity")
@Table(name = "mytable") 
//@ReadOnly
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
        name = "exampleFind", 
        query = "[..]", 
hints = {@QueryHint(name= QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value= "TRUE")})
})
@Cacheable
@Cache(type = CacheType.FULL)
public class MyEntity {
```

When I annotate this class with @ReadOnly then this query does not hit the database (uses results cache only) but when I remove @ReadOnly annotation it always performs SQL on database.

How to enable this cache without @ReadOnly? Are there any limitations on results cache?

I use EclipseLink 2.4.1

Answer (score 2):

In our application we had some trouble getting the query cache to work as well. You need to make sure that your entities and your query results are cached.

For us it works when we set the shared-cache-mode in the `persistence.xml` to `DISABLE_SELECTIVE`:

```
 <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

Together with this we use `@Cache` to configure the type of caching we want for our entities. And `@Cacheable(false)` to disable it for some.

According the [developers manual](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged#Section_3.7.1_-_The_shared-cache-mode_element) this setting actually is the default, so removing your current setting should also work.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not help. Is there any option to log/monitor caches in eclipselink to check if cache is enabled or when is refreshed? Maybe this cache is invalidated every time and this is the reason why there is always SQL query to database

Comment: You can ask for individual objects if they are cached in the shared cache. . This can be done using the IdentityMapAccessor: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching. There is plenty more performance measurement, but I have not yet tried those.Also you can set the logging for eclipselink to the finest details in your persistence.xml